# Want to grow from technical role to management role with no path ahead

Tags: management, career-development

I've been in technical roles as an engineer working in R&D for a couple companies for many years. During the pandemic I unofficially drifted away from more technical tasks to more of a project management and project engineer type role and I really enjoy this type of work. I've also been responsible for training and auditing other employees under my boss which I also really enjoyed in what I was told was to get my feet wet for a role which would be more of a manager type role.

The problem is my boss was overloaded with work and so the organizational structure was changed so I now report to a new boss in my same role. This new boss isn't bad except they have much different ideas about my growth and after a discussion a management role isn't on the road map for me, nor do I trust this individual that it ever will be.

I want to move forward with growing into a management role either in the company or elsewhere but I'm feeling stuck. I have searched jobs outside the company and the roles I'd like all require management experience which I was sort of doing but don't have the job title to back up. Anyone been in this situation? If so, any tips? Also, I'm considering using my current company's tuition reimbursement policy (free money, no strings attached at all) to get an MBA if that would help me land a manager role in or outside the company. Anyone have good or bad experiences going this route? An MBA seems to pale in comparison with actual work experience but I'm not sure what else to do. I like my job, my company, and my salary so I don't want to leave unless I know I'm moving forward with my personal career goals.

Answer (score 5):

> I have searched jobs outside the company and the roles I'd like all
> require management experience

You might need to widen your search to include other roles that don't require prior management experience. You might also consider using an agency who can vouch for your abilities, even if you don't have a management title yet.

Realistically, by far the easiest way to move into management is to get promoted within your own company. Are internal job opportunities posted in your company? If so, look to them.

Pretty much everyone who is a manager was a non-manager at some point in their career, so clearly this progression happens.

> I'm considering using my current company's tuition reimbursement
> policy (free money, no strings attached at all) to get an MBA if that
> would help me land a manager role in or outside the company.

That could easily help you down the road. If nothing else it will expand your professional network.

I got my MBA while working (in a low-level management role). It eventually helped me in landing a higher role in a startup company.

Comment: I appreciate the reply. I have given lots of thought to how the people I know made the jump to a leadership role and most do it from within the organization so I agree. However I've very infrequently seen these types of roles open up within my company because I think they get promoted within without posting the job. I'm thinking I'll make it crystal clear to my boss and others what my goals are while also starting an MBA program in the next year. If I don't find any opportunities when I'm done, then I'll begin expanding my search.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not Management (tried it once, I'm a terrible Manager...) - so I can't answer that part of your question - however the bit I will be answering is this:

Your company has a tuition policy, you *absolutely* should be leveraging that. Consider that this is part of your Salary - all the time you aren't using it for Upskilling, you are effectively leaving a percentage of your total renumeration package on the table.

If an MBA is what you feel passionate about or it's a requirement for management where you are, then do an MBA. If there are other courses/options that are more interesting to you - then do those - but yes, use the company provided resources - they are there to be used.

Comment: I agree. I'm gonna go for it.

Comment: If your company is willing to pay for you to get an MBA (mine explicitly excluded that as something they would pay for, though they'd allow some time flexibility for it), that implies there _is_ a process for putting yourself forward as interested in managing when the opportunity arises. It may be as simple as watching the internal job openings list and applying for first-level management positions. A current manager might be able to help you nail that down.

Comment: But often the way this works is that, like most promotions, you get promoted into a role that you have already demonstrated you can perform well in. So being a good team lead is an important first step, but you might ask your busy manager if there are other responsibilities that they might want to delegate to you, preferably with a reduction in your other workload to allow the needed time -- though that may be hard to get if they really need you where you are now.